# Why is my Register page appearing when I run login page?

Tags: python, tkinter

When I run my page for login it displays my register page. When I close my register page it appears. Anybody knows whats the issue?

Here is my login page

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image

import register
import pymysql




class Login:


def __init__(self,root):
    self.root=root
    self.root.title("Scheduling Management System")
    self.root.geometry("1350x768+0+0")
    self.root.resizable(False,False)

    self.txt_user = StringVar()
    self.txt_pass = StringVar()
    self.bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "Images/bgimage.jpg")
    bg = Label(self.root,image=self.bg).place(x = 0, y= 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)
    framelogin = Frame(self.root,bg="white")
    framelogin.place(x=450,y=100,height=500,width=700)

    title=Label(framelogin,text="Login Here",font=("Arial",30,"bold"),fg="orange",bg="white").place(x=90,y=30)
    nexttitle=Label(framelogin,text="Scheduling Staff System",font=("Times New Roman",18,"bold"),fg="orange",bg="white").place(x=90,y=100)

    userlabel=Label(framelogin,text="Username",font=("Arial",15,"bold"),fg="gray",bg="white").place(x=90,y=140)
    self.txt_user=Entry(framelogin,textvariable = self.txt_user,font=("times new roman",15),bg="lightgray")
    self.txt_user.place(x=90,y=170,width=350,height=35)

    passlabel=Label(framelogin,text="Password",font=("Arial",15,"bold"),fg="gray",bg="white").place(x=90,y=210)
    self.txt_pass=Entry(framelogin,textvariable = self.txt_pass,font=("times new roman",15),show="*",bg="lightgray")
    self.txt_pass.place(x=90,y=240,width=350,height=35)

    forget=Button(framelogin,text="Forgot Password",bg="white",fg="orange",font=("trebuchet ms",12)).place(x=90,y=305)
    reglabel=Label(framelogin,text="Don't Have an Account?",font=("trebuchet ms",12,"bold"),fg="orange",bg="white").place(x=320,y=310)
    registerbutton=Button(framelogin,text="Sign Up",command=register,bg="white",fg="orange",font=("trebuchet ms",12)).place(x=510,y=305)

    loginbutton=Button(framelogin,text="Login",command=self.login,fg="white",bg="orange",font=("sans serif ms",20)).place(x=90,y=350,width="100",height="40")

def login(self):
    if self.txt_user.get() == "" or self.txt_pass.get() == "":
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please fill up all fields!")


root = Tk()
obj = Login(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Here is my register page

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox

import PIL
import pymysql
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image

class Register:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Registration Page")
        self.root.geometry("1350x768+0+0")
        self.root.config(bg="light blue")

        self.bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="Images/bgimage.jpg")
        bg = Label(self.root,image=self.bg).place(x = 0, y= 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)
        frame1=Frame(self.root,bg="white")
        frame1.place(x=450,y=100,width=700,height=600)

        title=Label(frame1,text="Please enter your information here",font=("trebuchet ms",20,),bg="white",fg="black").place(x=50, y=30)


        fname=Label(frame1,text="First Name",font=("times new roman",15,"bold"),bg="white",fg="black").place(x=50, y=100)
        self.text_fname=Entry(frame1,font=("arial",15,),bg="lightgray")
        self.text_fname.place(x=50, y=130, width=250)
        lname=Label(frame1,text="Last Name",font=("times new roman",15,"bold"),bg="white",fg="black").place(x=370, y=100)
        self.text_lname=Entry(frame1,font=("arial",15,),bg="lightgray")
        self.text_lname.place(x=370, y=130, width=250)
        contact=Label(frame1,text="Contact Number",font=("times new roman",15,"bold"),bg="white",fg="black").place(x=50, y=170)
        self.text_contact=Entry(frame1,font=("arial",15,),bg="lightgray")
        self.text_contact.place(x=50, y=200, width=250)
        email=Label(frame1,text="Email Address",font=("times new roman",15,"bold"),bg="white",fg="black").place(x=370, y=170)
        self.text_email=Entry(frame1,font=("arial",15,),bg="lightgray")
        self.text_email.place(x=370, y=200, width=250)
        question=Label(frame1,text="Security Question",font=("times new roman",15,"bold"),bg="white",fg="black").place(x=50, y=240)
        self.cmbquestion=ttk.Combobox(frame1,font=("times new roman",13),state='readonly',justify=CENTER)
        self.cmbquestion['values']=("Select","Your First Car","Your Mothers First Name", "Your Best Friend Name")
        self.cmbquestion.place(x=50, y=270, width=250)
        self.cmbquestion.current(0)
        answer=Label(frame1,text="Answer",font=("times new roman",15,"bold"),bg="white",fg="black").place(x=370, y=240)
        self.text_answer=Entry(frame1,font=("arial",15,),bg="lightgray")
        self.text_answer.place(x=370, y=270, width=250)
        pwd=Label(frame1,text="Password",font=("times new roman",15,"bold"),bg="white",fg="black").place(x=50, y=310)
        self.text_pwd=Entry(frame1,font=("arial",15,),show="*",bg="lightgray")
        self.text_pwd.place(x=50, y=340, width=250)
        cfmpwd=Label(frame1,text="Confirm Password",font=("times new roman",15,"bold"),bg="white",fg="black").place(x=370, y=310)
        self.text_cfmpwd=Entry(frame1,font=("arial",15,),show="*",bg="lightgray")
        self.text_cfmpwd.place(x=370, y=340, width=250)

        self.btn= ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="images/register.png")
        btn = Button(frame1,image=self.btn, bd=0, command = self.registerdata,cursor = "hand2").place(x=50, y = 420)



    def registerdata(self):
        if self.text_fname.get()=="" or self.text_lname.get()=="" or self.text_contact.get()=="" or self.text_email.get()=="" or self.cmbquestion.get()=="Select" or self.text_pwd.get()=="" or self.text_cfmpwd.get()=="":
            messagebox.showerror("Error","All fields are required!",parent=self.root)
        elif self.text_pwd.get()!=self.text_cfmpwd.get():
            messagebox.showerror("Error","Passwords must be the same!",parent=self.root)
        else:
            try:
                con=pymysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="",database="employee")
                cur=con.cursor()
                cur.execute("select * from employeelist where email=%s", self.text_email.get())
                row=cur.fetchone()
                print(row)
                if row!=None:
                    messagebox.showerror("Error","User Already Exists. Please Register With a New Email",parent=self.root)
                else:
                    cur.execute("insert into employeelist (fname,lname,contact,email,question,answer,password) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",
                                (self.text_fname.get(),self.text_lname.get(),self.text_contact.get(),self.text_email.get(),self.cmbquestion.get(),self.text_answer.get(),self.text_pwd.get()))
                    con.commit() #do changes to database
                    con.close()
                    messagebox.showinfo("Success","Registration Successful",parent=self.root)
            except Exception as ex:
                messagebox.showerror("Error",f"Error due to: {str(ex)}",parent=self.root)
root = Tk()
obj = Register(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I do not know why when I run my login page it appears to my registration page but when I close my registration page it will show my login page. I have defined all variables accordingly but still am facing this error.

Comment: It could be that bought are a separate window,  you can inhere the `tk.Tk` and the `tk.Frame` like in one of mine [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65889213/11420630)

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code in your question. It would also be very helpful if you created a [mcve]. There's a lot of code that is unrelated to the problem being asked about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `import register` in the login file, it runs the code at the bottom of the file, so it is run first and the register window displays. Then once you close the register window, the code at the bottom of login is run and the login window is displayed. To avoid this, change the bottom of login to something like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    obj = Login(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

This will only run the code at the bottom if the file is run directly, not if it is imported, which should resolve your issue.

Comment: I have tried to amend the changes but it still shows my register page instead of login page

Comment: @JagdeeshSandhu Try adding it to the bottom both the login and register files. (Remember to change `obj = Login(root)` to `obj = Register(root)` on the register code)